# Chart Naming with Variable in VBA, Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to rename a chart with:

With ActiveChart

```
For i = 1 To Count_Rows
    j = i + 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = """=Sheet1!$A$" & j & Chr(34)
Next i
```

...

this is resolving to desired formula as "=Sheet1!$A$2" and so on...
but not naming the series with contents instead putting the name of the series as "=Sheet1!$A$2"

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a range object to return the cell values.

```
For i = 1 To Count_Rows
    j = i + 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = Range("Sheet1!$A$" & j)
Next i
```